# Partial View with parametrized prefix for controls names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a BarEditor.ascx, that can be called from diffent places.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.Bar>" %>
<%= Html.TextBox("a") %>
...
```

Now consider I need to edit two objects on one page Edit.aspx

```
    <form action="update">
        <div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", ViewData["bar"]); %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", ViewData["baz"]); %>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

This submits:

```
a=1&a=2
```

I need it to be:

```
bar.a=1&baz.a=2
```

So we can process it with

```
public ActionResult Update(Bar bar, Bar baz)
{
    ...
}
```

What is a best way to write reusable BarEditor.ascx that can generate prefixes for controls names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a ViewModel class for your BarEditor and make it strongly typed to this new class

e.g.

```
namespace ViewModel {
    public class BarEditor {

        string Prefix { get; set; }
        Models.Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now you create your textbox in BarEditor.ascx like this

```
<%= Html.TextBox(Model.Prefix + ".a") %>
```

and in your view you include the BarEditor like that

```
 <form action="update">
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", new ViewModel.BarEditor { Prefix = "Bar", Bar = ViewData["bar"]}); %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", new ViewModel.BarEditor { Prefix = "Baz", Bar = ViewData["baz"]}); %>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

hth

Comment: Yes, it looks like some thing like this is a way to go. It also can be a custom RenderPartial implementation. Let's consider this as answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a string ("baz" or "bar", etc) with my ViewData when calling the user control.  Have the html.textbox get its name from the text passed and its value from the value passed.

Comment: Let me be more specific...the control could accept a simple class (textboxdata{}) that has two properties: textboxName, textboxValue.  Prior to calling RenderPartial, instantiate the object and then pass it to the control.  You could create a enumerable list of the "textboxData" objects in your controller, so as to avoid this kind of action in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a model for the view? Your view would then need to be a strongly typed view using the data class FormView.

```
public class FormView
{
    string Bar {get; set;}
    string Baz {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your view you can use

```
<form action="update">
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", Model.Bar); %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", Model.Baz); %>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your controller becomes

```
public ActionResult Update(FormView MyForm)
{
    ... = MyForm.Bar;

    ... = MyForm.Baz;
}
```

Comment: 1. Why in your example FormView.Bar and FormView.Baz are of string type? 2. What you suggest does not work. We'll get a=1&a=2.

Comment: You can change it to BarEditor instead of string.  I do this in nearly all my projects and I never get a=1&a=2.

Comment: May be you are talking about some similar scenarios like: <%= Html.TextBox("Bar.a") %>, <%= Html.TextBox("Baz.a") %>. But notice, I am talking about RenderPartial. BTW, I think there is no solution without writing custom RenderPartial.

Comment: -1 this does not address the issue at all. The question was how to change the partial view such that the field names are rendered as "Bar.a" vs. "Baz.a" that does not depend on where the objects you pass stem from...

Answer (score -2):

You should to learn about Model Mapping in ASP.Net MVC. Everything in the asp.net mvc page will be rendered to html control therefore don't distinguish between controls in
    <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", ViewData["bar"]); %>
and
    <% Html.RenderPartial("BarEditor", ViewData["baz"]); %>

Comment: - The OP obviously understood how Model Mapping works which is why he asked for a solution to address his issue. You don't address that.