# Calling RenderPartial in a loop : Avoid when possible?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-2, loops, renderpartial

Is it generally best to avoid calling to render partial in a loop situation...

```
<%  foreach (var buildingRate in locationBuildingRate.BuildingRates)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("LocationBuildingRate", buildingRate);
    }
%>
```

And instead allow the rendering to loop inside the partial?  Does this second way avoid a lot of overhead?

```
Html.RenderPartial("LocationBuildingRate", locationBuildingRate.BuildingRates);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Calling a render partial inside a loop would request the rendering engine for each run. Better to do the second approach where you loop inside the partial..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to leverage EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates, which basically renders a partial but is less expensive.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of moving the loop code to within the partial? What benefits do the templates provide?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037580/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-vs-display-template-vs-editor-template/