# default model binding does not work in case when model contains a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Here are my model.

```
public class InfoModel
    {
        public NameModel Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

public class NameModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName  { get; set; }

        public NameModel(string first, string last)
        {
            this.FirstName = first;
            this.LastName = last;
        }
    }
```

Then I have a partial View just for displaying names as follows

```
@model MyTestApp.Models.NameModel

@Html.LabelFor( m => m.LastName) 
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.LastName)       
<br />
@Html.LabelFor( m => m.FirstName) 
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.FirstName)
```

Then there is a view for ShowInfo

```
@model MyTestApp.Models.InfoModel

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("ShowName", Model.Name)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Phone) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)
    <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Info" />
}
```

Now user submit any info, following controller method is called

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ShowInfo(InfoModel model)
 {
    ...
 }
```

Problem is when i inspect the value of model,  phone is fine but name is null. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` class uses `Activator.CreateInstance(typeToCreate)` internally to create the model classes. Your `NameModel` class dosn't have a default constructor so the `DefaultModelBinder` can't instantiate it. So if you add the default constructor it should work.

EDIT
It won't work Partial view you need to use an EditorTemplate instead:
Create a folder under your view folder with the name `EditorTemplates` and put your ShowName.cshtml there add in your main view use:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, "ShowName")
    ...
```

Comment: I've updated my answer and you will still need the default constructor :)

Comment: so I cannot use Partial view here and have to use EditorFor? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also if my ShowName class contains some other controls (like drop-down etc), not sure if using EditorFor will still work?

Comment: You can learn more about the difference between partial/editorfor in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037580/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-vs-display-template-vs-editor-template). Basically Partial views are not supporting the ModelMetaData based helpers so it won't render the right names for hierarchical models.

Answer (score -1):

The DefaultModelBinder  works if the Model class has a default constructor and the properties have get and set. In all other cases it doesn't work.

Example

```
public class Product
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

doesn't work.

```
public class Product
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}

    public Product()
    {
    }
}
```

works.