# Assign Action to dynamically created html buttons in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc.I created html buttons dynamically and I am unable to assign action for these buttons

Code is:

```
sb.Append("<li style=\"margin:17px;\">");
        sb.Append("<img src=\"" + path + "Content/HeaderSlides/FullImages/" 
                  + imagename + "\" width=\"180\" height=\"100\"/>");

        sb.Append("<input type=\"button\"  name=\"deleteimage" + id 
                  + " \" id=\"btndelete" + id 
                  + "\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"t-button t-grid-delete\" " 
                  + " style=\"margin-left:10px;\" />");
```

I want to make the html buttons something like this:

```
<input type="submit" 
       title="Delete" 
       value="Delete" 
       name="btndelete" 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteHeaderSlide", 
                                           "HeaderSlides",
                                           new { filename = "Sunset.jpg" })'" />
```

Comment: Only give complete code of creation of one button. Same will be for all others

Comment: Why are you creating html with strings? It's much better to use [helpers or templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037580/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-vs-display-template-vs-editor-template). Also, if your button simply changes the current page, why not use a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=btndelete]').bind('click', function() {
       window.location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteHeaderSlide", 
                                       "HeaderSlides",
                                       new { filename = "Sunset.jpg" })';
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create html button with your code the Simplest way to define/assign action is

```
string action = "<script>function yourFunction() {alert('hi');}</script>";
string btnCraeteCode = "<input type='button' onClick='yourFunction()' />";    
sub.Append(action+btnCraeteCode);
```

You can also have already defined yourFunction() defined in script in head tag of your page

In that case you do not need to add action string here before createButton