# Object DisplayFor Template Not Being Found

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, templates

Is there a reason `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Object.cshtml` is not being picked up by views when calling `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)`?

If I name the file `DateTime.cshtml` it is picked up by `DateTime` properties as is, but I don't want to have to create a template for each type. Shouldn't `Object.cshtml` just be used for everything?

I have not decorated the properties with any attributes.

The view's code:

```
@model Object

<div>
    <strong>@Model</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DisplayTemplates are not intended to use like this. You should create a `partial view` with this content:

```
@model Object

<div>
    <strong>@Model</strong>
</div>
```

And instead of this: `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)`

you write this: `@Html.Partial("YourPartialView", Model.Date)`

With this you achieve the result you want. A `DisplayTemplate` is a more specific thing.

Comment: Say I created template files for each type. Would it still be classified as "not intended"? I'm missing the point of them if I can't customize?

Comment: If you create the template files for each type explicitly then that would work but would be quite pointless

Comment: Here is an explanation of the differences of the concepts above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5037631/238682

Comment: Makes sense, but this leads to another question I have posted as a followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096530