# Partial And DisplayFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, templates

**First my model:**

```
public class Order
{
  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

**My view:**

```
@model Order
@Html.Partial("Display", Model.Date)
```

**Display partial:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x): <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x)</strong>
```

The label is not rendering. The DisplayFor renders the date fine. Also probably related, if I add an attribute to Order.Date `[DisplayName("Order Date")]` it is not honored. There something I am doing wrong? I simply want to apply a html convention to *all* my model properties for display. Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your partial is essentially strongly-typed for `DateTime`, not `Order`. This still works for `DisplayFor` because a `DateTime` will just call `ToString()` on itself. But, it has no name or inherent label, so `LabelFor` is going to do nothing for you.

The way you should be doing this, is actually passing the `Order` instance into the partial as the `Model`. Then:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date): <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Date)</strong>
```

Will get you what you're looking for.

Comment: I dont want to create Partials for every single one of my models just to simply wrap my display fields in html.

Comment: I'm obviously approaching this wrong. I simply want to call @Html.Something(x => x.Date) or @Html.Something(Model.Date) and have it use a predefined template. I can achieve this using Shared/DisplayTemplates but I would have to create a template for *each* property type.

Comment: Well you don't *have* to use partials, in the first place. Stuff this simple should just go in your view. If you're looking for a way to standardize display, you can investigate using Display Templates, but you're going to have the same problem with using stuff like `LabelFor`, i.e. you can't unless there's a greater context -- the information doesn't come from the specific property, but the model itself.

Comment: Also, I have no `@model` setting on my partial so I dont think "strongly-typed for DateTime" is correct.

Comment: I said "essentially". True, it's not strongly-typed at all, but the partial receives a `DateTime` so the `LabelFor` and `DisplayFor` methods act on a `DateTime` instance. `DateTime` has no inherent label, so you get nothing for that.

Comment: The plain and simple point is that `LabelFor` gets the label from the model's metadata. Unless you're interacting with the actual model, `LabelFor` isn't going to work.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks for your help. So I'm stuck with either repeating the html for every field in my view or creating DisplayFor templates for each property type?

Comment: I'm still stuck with this problem, I have literally 50+ views in a project, how can I standardize input forms accross the app? If I want to change the way input tags are wrapped I have to modify each of those forms/views. There has to be a better way. How is everyone else doing it on large apps?

Comment: Honestly, this isn't really a problem if you actually handle things properly. Namely, you shouldn't be determining the style or appearance of your display elements, form fields, etc. in HTML, but rather stick to generic HTML (`div`s and `span`s) with classes. Then if the appearance needs to change later, you don't have to change the HTML -- just the CSS -- and that *can* be done once for all.

Comment: You are right, thanks again for keeping me in check and not over thinking this.