# asp.net mvc 5 html.DisplayFor DisplayFormat Display(Name) not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

`Html.DisplayFor` stopped displaying the display name and the formatted string... My code is bellow ... any ideas? i have searched around any couldn't find anything. thanks

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime EventDateTimeDay { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Seconds")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00} s")]
public double Duration { get; set; }
```

Razor .cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<OurClass>
...
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventDateTimeDay)
        </th>

...
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
...
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDateTimeDay)
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  Am using Unity as an IOC and to reduce unity resolve errors I added this in the UnityConfig:

```
container.RegisterType<ModelMetadataProvider, EmptyModelMetadataProvider>();
```

which wiped out the data attributes. changed it to this and it worked fine:

```
container.RegisterInstance<ModelMetadataProvider>(ModelMetadataProviders.Current);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the DisplayName attribute

```
    [DisplayName("Seconds")]
    public double Duration { get; set; }
```

Comment: yes tried that too, that does not work.  thanks for responding tho.  and it doesn't explain why the DisplayFormat doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered in another post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976576/mvc-and-entity-framework-html-displaynamefor-with-composite-viewmodel[/link]