# How to include a large inline SVG in my View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, svg

I would like to avoid cluttering up my View (.cshtml) with the SVG-data. Is there a way to put it in a separate file and input this file in my view (like Latex' `\input{}`)?

Does it make sense to use a partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would highly suggest rendering partial views. It is an easy way to separate large amounts of html out if it is representative of data. You might also consider rendering a partial view with a template if you have a model that includes many occurrences of the same data.

Just replace your applicable html/data with a call to `@Html.Partial("ViewName")` or `@Html.Partial("ViewName", model)` where you'd like to clean up that clutter.

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037580/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-vs-display-template-vs-editor-template) on the efficiency of partial views vs. using model templates to separate html out of a view.