# paging and sorting issues having multiple grid.mvc grids in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I am trying to add 2 grid.mvc in the same page (with the same structure) and fitering, shorting and paging apply to both grids. I cannot to find proper documentation...but i have seen people uses GridRenderOptions.Create(gridName, viewName) shall I separate the grid in partial views or something like that??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]I prefer using editor templates for your solution

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstGrid)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondGrid)
```

Instead of partial view create two cshtml editor templates in shared folder.

Still please refer this for your final choice
[ASP.NET MVC 3 - Partial vs Display Template vs Editor Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037580/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-vs-display-template-vs-editor-template)

Comment: sorry but I do no unsderstand your answer.... I am using the GRID.MVC with sorting, filtering purpouses... the problem is when 2 GRID.MVC are included in the same page, the filtering, ordering and paging applies to both grids...

Comment: added a picture hope it helps