# Get partial value control value in controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I m working on asp.net mvc application.

i have one partial view in that one submit form and click on submit button than data will stored in database.
but when i get data from form collection than that form collection come null so how can i get partial view control's value in action method?

thanks in advance..

note : partial view is not strongly type.

Comment: Can you post code with how you do it now? (View + Controller).

Answer (score 0):

I think you encounter the same issue that is discussed here:

[ASP.NET MVC partial views: input name prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes)

To quickly investigate the issue, look at the source code of your page: do your controls from partials have the names you expect? If not, the article above will be helpful.