# Validation error in both partial views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Index page which has two partial view _Register and _Login. I have three viewmodels namely LoginViewModel,RegisterViewModel, LoginOrRegisterViewModel. Now,I want that if modelstate is not valid,I want to redirect back to index page having both login and register form.But, here , it redirect to view of register or login with validation in other viewmodel also.Please guide me regarding correct return type and correct view.

Index.cshtml

```
@model Project.ViewModels.LoginOrRegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
    @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.Registermodel)
    @Html.Partial("_Login", Model.Loginmodel)
```

_Register.cshtml

```
@model ProjectHub.ViewModels.RegisterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="label">@Html.Label("Name")</div>
    <div class="field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName)</div>
    <div class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)</div>


    //similar html for other attributes

    <input class="field" id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()   
}
```

_Login.cshtml

```
@model ProjectHub.ViewModels.LoginModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="label">@Html.Label("Username")</div>
    <div class="field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)</div>
    <div class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</div>

    <div class="label">@Html.Label("Password")</div>
    <div class="field">@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)</div>
    <div class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</div>

    <input class="field" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

ViewModels

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is Required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterModel
    {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is Required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is Required")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginOrRegisterModel
    {
         public LoginModel Loginmodel { get; set; }
         public RegisterModel Registermodel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

accountController

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LoginOrRegisterModel model = new LoginOrRegisterModel();
        model.Loginmodel = new LoginModel();
        model.Registermodel = new RegisterModel();
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginOrRegisterModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Login()
    {
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
        return View("_Login",model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel usermodel)
    {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
                //some validation loic
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View("Index", new LoginOrRegisterModel() { Loginmodel = usermodel, Registermodel = new RegisterModel() });
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username/Password");
            return View("Index",new LoginOrRegisterModel() { Loginmodel = usermodel, Registermodel = new RegisterModel() });
        }
    }

    public ViewResult Register()
    {
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
        return View("_Register",model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel usermodel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", new LoginOrRegisterModel() { Loginmodel = new LoginModel(), Registermodel = usermodel });
        }
        try
        {
            //Some logic for validation
            return RedirectToAction("activationemail", new { username = usermodel.Username, email = usermodel.Email });
        }
        catch (Exception ae)
        {
           return View("Index", new LoginOrRegisterModel() { Loginmodel = new      LoginModel(), Registermodel = usermodel });
        }
    }
```

Please help me,I got error [like this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=m819vm&s=6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add HtmlFieldPrefix when you rendering partial:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.Registermodel, new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Registermodel" } })
   @Html.Partial("_Login", Model.Loginmodel, new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Loginmodel" } })
   ```

   or use [PartialFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes)
2. Add in your action method BindAttribute with prefix:

   ```
   public ActionResult Register([Bind(Prefix = "Registermodel")]RegisterModel usermodel)
   public ActionResult Login([Bind(Prefix = "Loginmodel")]LoginModel usermodel)
   ```