# Model binding a collection property with a partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}
```

And I want a view of `Foo` that lets users edit `Bar` items.  But with a catch: I want the `Bar` editing to be handled by a partial view.

```
@model Web.ViewModels.Foo

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.Partial("_EditBars", Model.Bars)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment)
    ...
}
```

The `_EditBars` partial view looks something like:

```
@model List<Web.ViewModels.Bar>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Baz)
}
```

I want this to model bind to my action, which looks something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Foo foo) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, this is the data that I'm posting, which doesn't model bind the `Bars` property:

```
[1].Baz=10&[0].Baz=5&Comment=bla
```

It makes sense that this doesn't work, because it's missing the `Bars` prefix.  If I understand correctly, I need it to be this:

```
Bars[1].Baz=10&Bars[0].Baz=5&Comment=bla
```

So, I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807655/546561):

```
@Html.Partial(
    "_EditBars",
    Model.Bars,
    new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
    {
        TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
        {
            HtmlFieldPrefix = "Bars"
        }
    })
```

But that's not working either.  With that, I'm getting:

```
Bars.[1].Baz=10&Bars.[0].Baz=5&Comment=bla
```

I assume that that isn't working because of the extra period (`Bars.[1]` vs. `Bars[1]`).  Is there anything I can do to get the result that I desire?

**Note:** This is a major oversimplification of my actual situation.  I recognize that with something this simple, the best approach would probably be to make an `EditorTemplate` for `Bar` and loop through using `EditorFor` in my view.  If possible, I'd like to avoid this solution.

Comment: @gdp, edited to show the partial view, and added a note to the bottom of my question. Thanks!

Comment: did you ever solve it in the end? having the same problem

Comment: It's been a while, so I don't remember the details, but looking at my commit logs, I committed something after asking this question that referenced this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes/6292180#6292180, which I believe may be related.

Comment: @user3281466, forgot to tag you, and I'm not sure if editing my comment to tag you will send you a notification.

Comment: thanks for that, I solved my problem but will look into the topic you mentioned for additional information.

Answer (score 4):

As you do not want to use an `EditorTemplate` for `Bar`, a solution of your scenario could be:

Change the @model type of the '_EditBars' partial view  to `Foo` and view should be like:

```
@model Foo

@if (Model.Bars != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++)
     {
         @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Bars[i].Baz)
     }
}
```

(It would be better to change the partial view's name to `'_EditFooBars'`)

Hope this helps.