# How can I make sure model binding will work as expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm programming in C# ASP.NET MVC4 (Razor engine).  I have a need to create a partial view and reuse it in multiple places.  The problem is that the view is a form, and in some cases I will need to use it with a ViewModel.  My question is how the model binding will work because in a ViewModel it will be a property of a property.  Example:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class OfficeViewModel
{
    public PersonModel Person { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

The partial view for the PersonModel would be:

```
@model SomeNameSpace.PersonModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
```

When this view is rendered it would look like this:

```
<input type="textbox" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
<input type="textbox" id="LastName" name="LastName" />
```

Now I want to use this same view with my OfficeViewModel.  In that case I would do this in my Office view:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Person", Model.Person); }
```

When this partial view is rendered it will be rendered as shown above.  If I were to NOT reuse that view, my Office view will be like this:

```
@model SomeNameSpace.OfficeViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.LastName)
```

That would be rendered as:

```
<input type="textbox" id="Person_FirstName" name="Person.FirstName" />
<input type="textbox" id="Person_LastName" name="Person.LastName" />
```

Notice how the **name** attribute has the **Person** prefix property.  So if I use the RenderPartial option and pass in the Model.Person, will the model binder know where to bind the **FirstName** and **LastName** in the OfficeViewModel?

If the model binder is smart enough to check for properties of properties, what happens when I have a *ManagerModel* and *EmployeeModel* in the OfficeViewModel and they both have properties named FirstName and LastName?

I hope I have been clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have property named Manager of type ManagerModel, model binder will map manager's first and lastname to respective properties of ManagerModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gerald is right. Default `RenderPartial` won't figure it out. Though you can write a custom helper that will take care of that issue:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PartialFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName)
{
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    object model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model;
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
    {
        TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo
        {
            HtmlFieldPrefix = name
        }
    };

    return helper.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);
}
```

Use it in the View like that:

```
@Html.PartialFor(x => x.Person, "Person")
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Html.RenderPartial does not carry over the information necessary to come up with the correct field names in this situation.

If you want to reuse a partial view in this way, look into using Editor Templates with Html.EditorFor instead. Like the other *For helpers, EditorFor takes a lambda expression which allows it to carry over the name of the property being passed in to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807655/78739

Basically I need to set the **ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix**.

So I added a property to the PersonModel and called it **HtmlFieldPrefix**.  Example:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string HtmlFieldPrefix { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my partial view I do this:

```
@model SomeNameSpace.PersonModel

@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Model.HtmlFieldPrefix;
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
```

In my controller action I can do this:

```
model.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Person";

return View("_Person", model);
```

Now my rendered view will look like this:

```
<input type="textbox" id="Person_FirstName" name="Person.FirstName" />
<input type="textbox" id="Person_LastName" name="Person.LastName" />
```

If I leave the model.HtmlFieldPrefix as null, the view will render as:

```
<input type="textbox" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
<input type="textbox" id="LastName" name="LastName" />
```

So this fixes my issue, and allows me to use the partial view with ViewModels.

Comment: Use caution, this could become hard to manage. Imagine refactoring a few different property names; you would have to find all the strings and change them. I advise against this approach.