# ASP.NET MVC: Binding dynamically rendered partial views as nested properties of the view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, data-binding

I have the following view models:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }
    public PayPalAccount PayPalAccount { get; set; }
}

public class BankAccount
{
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PayPalAccount
{
    public string PayPalEmail { get; set; }
}
```

In my single view I have a form that binds the `Person` model and also has a `DropDownList` that let's the user choose an account type.

Once the user makes his choice, I load dynamically using jQuery ajax one of the partial views that represent either the `BankAccount` or the `PayPalAccount` and I add it to the page.

After the user clicks submit, I call this action:

```
public ActionResult Save(Person person)
{ 
    // Here I expect that either person.BankAccount or person.PayPalAccount 
    // will contain the user input, and the other will be null
}
```

How do I make the partial view properties bind to the nested property in my `Person` view model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form fields must be prefixed (with `BankAccount.` or `PayPalAccount.`) so that they can be automatically bound.

When you return your partial view from Ajax, withthe current model you're using, their names don't have a prefix.

The easier way to prefix them is using exactly the same View Model class: `Person` for both partial views. If you do that, in the Razor you'll have to write

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BankAccount.BankName)
```

The generated input field will have the required prefix `BankAccount.`, i.e. it will look like this: `<input ... name='BankAccount.BankName' ... />`

You could also create a view model like this for your partial:

```
public class BakAccountModel
{
   // make sure the property name is the same as in the Person view model
   public BankAccount { get; set; } 
}
```

An finally, you can try a solution like this:
[ASP.NET MVC partial views: input name prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes)

I can't assure the last solution will work fine: for example it could break the `ModelState`. And is harder to implemente and "less standard".