# getting the values from a nested complex object that is passed to a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

I have a ViewModel that has a complex object as one of its members.  The complex object has 4 properties (all strings).  I'm trying to create a re-usable partial view where I can pass in the complex object and have it generate the html with html helpers for its properties.  That's all working great.  However, when I submit the form, the model binder isn't mapping the values back to the ViewModel's member so I don't get anything back on the server side.  How can I read the values a user types into the html helpers for the complex object.

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
     public MyComplexModel ComplexModel { get; set; }
}
```

MyComplexModel

```
public class MyComplexModel
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     ....
}
```

Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
          model.ComplexModel = new MyComplexModel();
          model.ComplexModel.id = 15;
          return View(model);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
     {
          // model here never has my nested model populated in the partial view
          return View(model);
     }
}
```

View

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
     ....
     @Html.Partial("MyPartialView", Model.ComplexModel)
}
```

Partial View

```
@model my.path.to.namespace.MyComplexModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
...
```

how can I bind this data on form submission so that the parent model contains the data entered on the web form from the partial view?

thanks

EDIT: I've figured out that I need to prepend "ComplexModel." to all of my control's names in the partial view (textboxes) so that it maps to the nested object, but I can't pass the ViewModel type to the partial view to get that extra layer because it needs to be generic to accept several ViewModel types.  I could just rewrite the name attribute with javascript, but that seems overly ghetto to me.  How else can I do this?

EDIT 2: I can statically set the name attribute with new { Name="ComplexModel.Name" } so I think I'm in business unless someone has a better method?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can pass the prefix to the partial using

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", Model.ComplexModel, 
    new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "ComplexModel" }})
```

which will perpend the prefix to you controls `name` attribute so that `<input name="Name" ../>` will become `<input name="ComplexModel.Name" ../>` and correctly bind to typeof `MyViewModel` on post back

**Edit**

To make it a little easier, you can encapsulate this in a html helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString PartialFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName)
{
  string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  object model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model;
  var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
  {
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo 
    { 
      HtmlFieldPrefix = string.IsNullOrEmpty(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix) ? 
        name : $"{helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix}.{name}"
    }
  };
  return helper.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);
}
```

and use it as

```
@Html.PartialFor(m => m.ComplexModel, "MyPartialView")
```

Comment: this looks very promising.  I've left the office for the day but will give it a shot tomorrow when I get back and mark as the answer if it works for me.  thanks.

Comment: boo...I can't upvote it because it says I have to have 15 reputation.  +1 for you though as soon as I get the 15 rep :)

Comment: @BlairHolmes, Added a html helper method to make this a little easier

Comment: In my opinion This helper should be built in the Mvc framework.

Comment: @Christian, What are you talking about? - it is MVC (or do you mean it should be part of the source code?)

Comment: Part of source code mate. Its too vital even for basic create pages.

Comment: @Christian, In a way it already is, because the correct approach is to use `EditorFor()` with a custom `EditorTemplate` for nested models (and the `EditorFor()` method passes the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as per the code above). Partials were not really designed to be used in this scenario which is why I assume the MVC team did not include it)

Comment: The use of EditorFor is "too conventional" (strict naming convetions, folder structure) and finally is altering the output html. The second solution is to pass the parent model which also is a wrong approach because it becomes not reusable anymore.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _altering the output html_ - using an `EditorTemplate` correctly will always generate the correct html. And a lot of the MVC framework is based around conventions.

Comment: Well when conventions become constraints then its not a convention anymore. Also if there is a convention in place it doesn't mean that it is a good one. Eg: Simply take the default folder structure. It comes with a  nearly "folder per extension type convention".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105692/discussion-between-christian-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Oh thank god, I was looking for this for hours! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

If you use tag helpers, the `partial` tag helper accepts a `for` attribute, which does what you expect.

```
<partial name="MyPartialView" for="ComplexModel" />
```

Using the `for` attribute, rather than the typical `model` attribute, will cause all of the form fields within the partial to be named with the `ComplexModel.` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

You can try passing the ViewModel to the partial.

```
@model my.path.to.namespace.MyViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComplexModel.Name)
```

**Edit**

You can create a base model and push the complex model in there and pass the based model to the partial.

```
public class MyViewModel :BaseModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

 public class MyViewModel2 :BaseModel
{
    public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public MyComplexModel ComplexModel { get; set; }
}
public class MyComplexModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then your partial will be like below :

```
@model my.path.to.namespace.BaseModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComplexModel.Name)
```

If this is not an acceptable solution, you may have to think in terms of overriding the model binder. You can read about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

Comment: I can't do that because it needs to be generic.  There will be several parent ViewModels that have their own type that will need to be passed in...See my first edit in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation and with the help of such informative posts changed my partial code to have prefix on generated in input elements generated by partial view

I have used Html.partial helper giving partialview name and object of ModelType and an instance of ViewDataDictionary object with Html Field Prefix to constructor of Html.partial.

This results in GET request of "xyz url" of "Main view" and rendering partial view inside it with input elements generated with prefix e.g. earlier Name="Title" now becomes Name="MySubType.Title" in respective HTML element and same for rest of the form input elements.

The problem occurred when POST request is made to "xyz url", expecting the Form which is filled in gets saved in to my database. But the MVC Modelbinder didn't bind my POSTed model data with form values filled in and also ModelState is also lost. The model in viewdata was also coming to null.

Finally I tried to update model data in Posted form using TryUppdateModel method which takes model instance and html prefix which was passed earlier to partial view,and can see now model is bound with values and model state is also present.

Please let me know if this approach is fine or bit diversified!

Answer (score 0):

I bumped onto this issue and solution but I was using dotnet core. So I've used David Carek's solution and converted it to it's dotnet core variant:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static Task<IHtmlContent> PartialForAsync<TModel, TProperty>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        string partialViewName
    )
    {
        if (htmlHelper == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(htmlHelper));
        }

        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }

        if (partialViewName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(partialViewName));
        }

        string name = htmlHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        object model = htmlHelper.GetModelExpression(expression).Model;
        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(htmlHelper.ViewData)
        {
            TemplateInfo =
            {
                HtmlFieldPrefix = string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)
                    ? name
                    : $"{htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix}{(name.StartsWith('[') ? "" : ".")}{name}"
            }
        };

        return htmlHelper.PartialAsync(partialViewName, model, viewData);
    }

    public static string GetExpressionText<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var expressionProvider = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetService(typeof(ModelExpressionProvider)) as ModelExpressionProvider;

        if (expressionProvider == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to retrieve ModelExpressionProvider from DI");
        }

        return expressionProvider.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }

    public static ModelExpression GetModelExpression<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var expressionProvider = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetService(typeof(ModelExpressionProvider)) as ModelExpressionProvider;

        if (expressionProvider == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to retrieve ModelExpressionProvider from DI");
        }

        return expressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(htmlHelper.ViewData, expression);
    }
}
```

Usage also adapts a bit:

```
@await Html.PartialForAsync(m => m.ComplexModel, "MyPartialView")
```

I've also added a small adaptation where there's no added `.` in case your model expression starts with a `[` to be able to cope with lists (e.g. `list[1]`).

If anyone knows a better way of reaching the same result in dotnet core, feel free to react.