# Composite model not binding mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have created two models, Student and School and a composite model, StudentSchool.  I am using two different partiel views to create one the Student and the other the School.  However, in my controller, I am getting null values for both the Student and School.  Below is my code:

Student:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LayoutProject.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int studentID { get; set; }
        public String firstname { get; set; }
        public String lastname { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

School:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LayoutProject.Models
{
    public class School
    {
        public int schoolID { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String add { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Composite model, StudentSchool:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace LayoutProject.Models
{
    public class StudentSchool
    {
        public Student student { get; set; }
        public School school { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PartielViewStudent:

```
   @model LayoutProject.Models.Student

<h4>Student</h4>

            @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.studentID) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.studentID)

            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.firstname) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.firstname)

            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.lastname) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.lastname)

            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.year) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.year)

            <br />
```

PartialViewSchool:

```
    @model LayoutProject.Models.School

<h4>School</h4>


        @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.schoolID) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.schoolID)

        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.name) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.name)

        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(d=>d.add) : @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.add)

        <br />
```

The View:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "StudentSchool";
}


<h2>StudentSchool</h2>
<form action="/Home/CreateStudentSchools" method="post">

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {


        @Html.Partial("_PartialViewStudent")

        @Html.Partial("_PartialViewSchool")
    }

    <input id="createSD" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateStudentSchools(StudentSchool ss)
        {
            return View("CreateStudentSchool");
        }
```

Any idea what I might be missing here?  Been with this since 4 days.

Comment: Your generating inputs with `name="studentID"` when you need to be creating `name="Student.studentID"` in order to bind to your model. You should be using an `EditorTemplate`, and `EditorFor(m => m.Student)`, not a partial.

Comment: Also you should make use of your composite model e.g.... `@model LayoutProject.Models.StudentSchool.student` you are looking for StudentSchool in the controller but from what I can see you never populate it

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: I was asked to use only partial views...

Comment: @hjardine:  I don't get what you mean. Where should I populate StudentSchool?

Comment: I have added an alternative for that in my answer, but the correct usage is an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: @tabby Follow Stephens answer, should work fine

Comment: @hjardine: Yep, you are right!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move you 'partial' views into the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and rename them to `Student.cshtml` and `School.cshtml` respectively (to match the names of the classes).  Then in the main view use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Student)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.School)
}
```

The inputs your generating will now contain the correct `name` attribute for binding to your view model, for example `name="Student.studentID"` instead of the current `name="studentID"`

Note: As an alternative, you can pass the HtmlFieldPrefix to a Partial as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907).

Comment: You are right, I will accept your answer!  :D  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

Its not a good idea if you provide the two partial views with different models  and combining in one model.You have to pass the reference of the composite model to your partial views.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewStudent",Model.student)

    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewSchool",Model.school)
}
```

This will work fine as with this approach as everything in the form is strictly typed.

In partial views also you have to specify models as

```
@model LayoutProject.Models.StudentSchool.student

@model LayoutProject.Models.StudentSchool.school
```

I am not sure about your [httpget] create method but it should be like
`[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateStudentSchools(StudentSchool ss)
        {
             var studentsc=new  StudentSchool()
        {
            student=new Student(),
            school=new School()
        }
            return View("CreateStudentSchool",studentsc);
        }`

Comment: When I try this : @Html.Partial("_PartialViewStudent",Model.student), I get an error:  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @tabby, You need to pass a model to the partial - either initialize a default `Student` and `School` in the controller, or use `@Html.Partial("_PartialViewStudent", new Student())` - But this wont work anyway - it will not add the prefix to the `name` attribute so binding will fail when you post.

Comment: @Prashant Mohite:  I did that as well but same error.  I guess the best way is to use Editor Templates as in the first answer.  I appreciate your help and quick response to my answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PrashantMohite, Your edited code will NOT work - it cannot bind to `StudentSchool` when the form is submitted.