# MVC: unable to postback ViewModel to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below is my view-model

```
public class ModelA
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string age {get;set;}
    public ModelB modelB {get;set;}
}
```

Here is partial view: _PartialView

```
@model ModelB
@*Bind all the into control*@
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name1)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name2)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name3)
```

Here is view

```
@model ModelA
using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "AreaName", new AjaxOptions()
{
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     OnSuccess = "BusinessPartner",
     OnFailure = "ErrorThrown"

}, new { name = "My App", id = "My App" }))
{
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age)
    @Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model.modelB)
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary tabSubmit tab1" id="tab1Next" value="Save and Proceed" />
}
```

When I do a postback to the controller, I'm able to get the value in ModalA but ModalB is null.
If I pass the whole Model instead of Model.modelB into the partial view, I'm able to get all the value.
Is this a expected behavior for MVC? or do I need any configuration?

Comment: where is your controller action method code ?

Comment: if you are using partial view like this, then you have to use both viewmodels in acton parameter eg. public ActionResult MyAction(ModelA modelA,ModelB modelB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model.modelB)
```

with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.modelB)
```

and rename your partial to

```
/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ModelB.cshtml
```

so that its an `EditorTemplate` (note the name of the file must be the same as the name of the class). You can also locate it in `/Views/yourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folder)

Alternatively, you need to specify the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907)

Note that if you inspect the html you partial is currently generating, it will include

```
<input name="Name1" ... />
```

whereas it needs to be

```
<input name="modelB.Name1" ... />
```

in order to bind to your model. Using an `EditorTemplate` rather than a partial will generate the correct `name` attributes

Comment: Thx. Will have a look on the alternative solution as well :)