# MVC parent child kind of model form submit doesn't send child collection to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, form-submit

I have a company model and it has employees list model as shown below

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeModel> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

and the Employee model as below

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

and my parent view is as shown below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CompanySignupSuccess", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "horizontal-form", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Logo:</label>
            <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo"                    accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" /> 

        </div>
        <div id="managerList">

            <div id="editorRowsManagers">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Managers)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("DetailsView", item)
                }
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </div>            
}
```

and the partial view shown below

```
@model yourAssembly.EmployeeModel
<div style="border:1px solid;margin:20px; padding:10px;">
    Manager Details:
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label" }) <span class="required">*</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone, new { @class = "control-label" }) <span class="required">*</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { @class = "form-control phoneno" })
    </div>

</div>
```

When I click on submit button, the model that goes to controller does have only Name and Logo properties filled in and the list object(Managers) is null, so I am not sure what is that I am missing here. BTW, I used the list of employees , because I would like add more employees by having a 'Add' button, and the Add button will just render another partial view.

```
public ActionResult CompanySignupSuccess(Company model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         //do some process
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Data entered.");
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View("CompanySignup", Model);
}
```

Can anyone please help me on how to send the child list object along with some properties on parent class when the Submit button is hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use a partial to generate controls for a collection unless you pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907) for an example). However the correct way to do this is to use an `EditorTemplate`. Rename your partial to `EmployeeModel.cshtml` (i.e. to match the name of the class) and move it to the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (or `/Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folder).

Then replace your loop in the view with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Managers)
```

which will correctly generate the necessary `name` attributes for binding, i.e

```
<input ... name="Managers[0].Name" />
<input ... name="Managers[1].Name" />
```

etc (currently all your generating is duplicate `name` attributes (and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I tried your suggestion but somehow the html didn't render properly. I am not sure how to insert an image in the comments section, I took a snapshot of what it rendered and my DevelperTools to show you.

Comment: What did not render properly? The solution I showed you works fine.

Comment: <li>
<input type="hidden" name="Managers.index" autocomplete="off" value="8f1c28b0-450d-441d-b990-17c0e2144ddc">
 </li>

Comment: The above is what rendered on screen upon changing the loop in main view as @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Managers)

Comment: What? No where do you even have a `<li>` element. And the fact you have generated `Managers.Index` with a `Guid` suggests you might be using `BeginCollectionItem` which you have not mentioned at all in your question or the code.

Comment: I am sorry, am not expert in MVC, but I didn't use BeginCollectionItem anywhere

Comment: BTW, do I need to change anything on my partial view after moving it to EditorTemplates?

Comment: No. But its not possible that your generating that hidden input unless you have some other code you have not shown us (and I am assuming that you actually have `@model yourAssembly.EmployeeModel` at the top of that partial. If there is anything else in it, edit your question to show the all the code in that partial)

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I have that @model yourAssembly.EmployeeModel, will update my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122034/discussion-between-bhaskar-and-stephen-muecke).