# Returning a partial view from controller with proper id and name in inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview, razor-pages

I'm developing a web MVC application with net core 2.2.

I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The following view:

```
@model A

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Bs.Count; i++)
{
    <partial name="_BsPatialView" for="Bs[i]" />
}
```

And the following partial view (_BsPatialView.cshtml):

```
<input type='hidden' asp-for="@Model.Id" />
<input asp-for="@Model.Name" />
```

Until here, everything it-s been generated fine. An example of the created inputs in the partial view is:

- `<input type="hidden" id="Bs_3__Id" name="Bs[3].Id" />`
- `<input type="text" id="Bs_3__Name" name="Bs[3].Name" />`

With the elements name and ids the model binder in the controller can properly bind everything.

The problem is when I try to return the partial view from the controller. What I do is:

```
public IActionResult AddBElement(A a)
{
    a.Bs.Add(new B() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    return PartialView("_BsPatialView", a.Bs.Last());
}
```

The resulting html is:

- `<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" />`
- `<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />`

So then, when I submit a form in which these inputs are, the model binding fails.

So, how should I return the partial view from the controller to fix this? Is there any equivalent to the partial's tag helper `for` attribute to use on the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Model binding uses field names to map them to Model properties. Now because your name does not contain any information about the parent class, `A`, model binder does not know how to bind them.

So in other words, model binder would know how to bind this input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Bs_3__Id" name="A.Bs[3].Id" />
```

But not this input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Bs_3__Id" name="Bs[3].Id" />
```

One solution would be pass the prefix, `A` to the partial view: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907)

A better solution would be to use `EditorTemplate` instead of Partial View, which would generate correct name for your input field. To use `EditorTemplate` Rename your partial view to B.cshtml (this should be your class name) and put it under `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder... then you can use it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bs)
```

[Check this tutorial for more info about Editor Templates](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/)

[Also check this question, which is very similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870582/mvc-binder-fails-to-bind-complex-viewmodel-property-in-form-submit)

Comment: The thing is that I want to load that partial from the server and append it to the place where the other Bs are. Anyway, I have change the design to avoid this issue. Thanks for the answer!