# How to get Id of property from child view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dom, razor, html-helper

I have **ViewModel** for example

```
class CustomerViewModel {
// ...
public string Name {get; set;}
public CategoryViewModel CategoryVM {get; set;}
}

class CategoryViewModel {
// ... 
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In **View** i can get Id of an html element with html helper

```
<!-- Customer Name -->
@Html.IdFor(m => m.Name)

<!-- Category Name -->
@Html.IdFor(m => m.CategoryVM.Name)
```

But what if `CategoryVM` is inserted into **PartialView**

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/.../_Category.cshtml", Model.CategoryVM);}
```

How to get Id of the property ? Because now i have two id's with same name.
What is best practice for properties naming and handling in nested ViewModels ?

Also i dont want to pass whole Model to the PartialView because there are Ajax calls, which re-renders the partial view, and i dont want to build whole Model from scratch even for simple operations.

Comment: I don't understand what is your issue. you could use `@Html.IdFor(m => m.Name)` inside your partial view . Your model inside of partial view is `Model.CategoryVM` .

Comment: Having duplicate `id` attributes is invalid html. And do not use partial views for nested objects (although you can is you pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907)) Use an `EditorTemplate` so you iputs are correctly named.

Comment: @Hadee: because i need to use the Id selector in the javascript and i dont have that javascript in the partialview to prevent re-rendering static script.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i will try the HtmlFieldPrefix, that seems very good thank you, but i dont understand why not to use partial view for nested object ?

Comment: Look at the html your generating for the nested object - it does not have the correct prefix (which needs to be `CategoryVM.Name`). And use an `EditorTemplate`, not the `HtmlFieldPrefix`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will try it, but is there a reason to use EditorTemplate rather then HtmlFieldPrefix ? because Prefix seems to solve my problem and it seems simpler.

Comment: Simpler?? Just rename you partial to `CategoryViewModel.cshtml` (to match the name of the class) and move it to the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder. Then in the main view its `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CategoryVM)` - why - because that what `EditorTempates` are designed for!

Comment: and that template file can be returned as partial view via ajax, (when i need to rerender the controls) great! only the "shared" folder can be confusing, because viewmodel is used only one