# Client Side Validations not working for second row in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Model as below:

```
public class User
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        [Range(0, 9999)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
public string Mask { get; set; }
}
```

**And then controller returns IQueryable  of above model**

There are two views. Parent view and then partial view which renders each row from the Model

**Main View**

```
@model IQueryable<User>
@{
    var Array = Model.ToArray();

}
//Header here
            <tbody id="table-body-vlan">
                @{
                    for (var i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Html.RenderPartial("_AddRow", Array [i], new ViewDataDictionary() { { "Index", i } });
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    }
```

**And then partial view **

```
@model User
@{
    var index = ViewData["Index "];
}

<tr class="js-deletable-item" id="row-@index" data-id="@Model.ID" >

    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(v => Model.ID, new {Name = "ID[" + index + "]", id = "id-" + Model.ID, Value = Model. ID > 0 ? Model. ID.ToString() : ""})
    </td>
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(v => Model.Name, new {Name = "Id[" + index + "].Name", data_val = "false" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Issue as below:**
If there are 10 records in the IQueryable then client side validations applies only to first row.

e.g. if I type 101S for ID field in first row I gets the warning (By changing the background color) that invalid ID.
But if I do same for second or other rows then I don't see background color change. Client side validations (defined through Data Annotations) are applying only  for first row.

I guess after first row rendered it is not adding those Annotation related properties to the other rows.

Comment: Your generating `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model (not sure what awful hacks you mus be using in the POST method to make this work. Use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `User` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) or if you really want to use a partial, then you need to pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907)

Comment: And NEVER NEVER attempt to change the `name` or `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method

Comment: tx Stephen. Actually I have not written the code but fixing some of the bugs. Finally did resolve it with suggestions given here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Editor and Display Templates](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/) in MVC:

Create an editor template here : `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/User.cshtml` like this:

```
@model User
<tr class="js-deletable-item">
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
    </td>
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
```

This will automatically be rendered for each element of your model whenever you call `EditorForModel`.

In your controller, do a `.ToList()` on your `IQueryable<User>()` object, before sending to the view.

In the Main View:

```
@model IEnumerable<User>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Much simpler and cleaner right? But the main advantage of using these templates is, they will automatically create appropriate `name` attributes. Something like:

```
<input data-val="true" name="[0].Id" value="" />
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[0].ID"></span>
```

Each row gets a unique `name` attribute. In your code, all your rows have the same `name="ID"` and `data-valmsg-for="ID"`. Because of this, only first row is getting validated.

The `name` attributes are also crucial when forms containing `collections` are being submitted. Otherwise, the User list will end being `null` when you submit ([Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)).

If you don't want to use `EditorTemplates`, you'd have to do a `for` loop (not `foreach`) and populate the rows.

Comment: In the Jqury I added ("#FornName").valid(). And it brings back client side validations.