# ASP.NET Core - TagHelper, Partial Views and property name conflict

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In an ASP.NET Core MVC project, say I have two partial views `_viewA` and `_viewB` and two  associated models `ModelA` and `ModelB`.

And say both `ModelA` and `ModelB` have a property called `MyProperty`.
Then in both `_viewA` and `_viewB` I use `asp-for="MyProperty"`.

My issue is that my page ends up with two html elements with the same id.
How can I avoid that?
Note that I don't want to rename MyProperty as my models should not care about UI constraints.

Comment: Do not use partials - use `EditorTemplates` (but if you do use partials, you need to pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907) for an example

Comment: That's it! I had to slightly update PartialFor with .net core but tks!

Comment: I tried to find a dupe for asp.net-core-mvc, but could not, so you might want to add your own answer with the modified code.

Comment: I always rename the id of the inputs. I don't like the auto generated ids. Sometimes you have to do so, i.e., radio buttons. And with Core 2.0 and TagHelper, it's easier than ever to do the renaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tks to [@stephen-muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) as well as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907) I've solved the problem with `HtmlFieldPrefix`. Here is an extension method that works with .Net Core to be used in `@html.PartialFor("_viewA", "viewAPrefix")`. Then all ids and names within the partial view are prefixed (even without using `asp-for`).

```
public static IHtmlContent PartialFor(this IHtmlHelper helper, string partialViewName, string prefix)
{
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData);
    var htmlPrefix = viewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    viewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix += !Equals(htmlPrefix, string.Empty) ? $".{prefix}" : prefix;
    return helper.Partial(partialViewName, viewData);
}
```