# asp mvc partial view model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've this data model

```
public partial class UsersInfo
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name_f { get; set; }
    public string Name_l { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveAccount { get; set; }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public virtual UsersInfo UsersInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and i'm rendering this form

```
@model LoanApp.Models.DataBaseModel.Employee
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Contoler, "Employe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_userInfo.cshtml",Model.UsersInfo)
    <label class="control-label">يعمل في فــرع</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("BranchID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn default" />
}
```

and this is my partial view

```
@model LoanApp.Models.DataBaseModel.UsersInfo
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name_f, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "الاسم الاول", @required = "" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name_l, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "الاسم الاخير", @required = "" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "", @number = "true" })
```

I want my post edit method to has the object from `userinfo` instead of `null`, I'm not sure what i'm missing

I've one to one relation between table employee and users info

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Fjf.png)

Comment: Where is your form ? How does your HttpPost action method looks like and what is your expected behavior ?

Comment: I think complex properties are not automatically serialized.

Comment: You need to show your POST method. Your generating form controls for `ChildViewModel` which will not match your model. Use an `EditorTemplate`, not a partial so the `name` attributes are correctly prefixed

Comment: And if you did want to use a partial, then you need to pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` to the partial as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907)

Comment: i've updated mu code and and added an image

Comment: Change your `_userInfo.cshtml` partial to `UsersInfo.cshtml` (t match the name of the model, and then move it to the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, and then replace `@Html.Partial()` with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UsersInfo)` and your form controls will be correctly named. (look at the `name` attributes before and after you make the change to understand)

Comment: And remove your `new { @required = "" }` - that makes no sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke , i did every thing and for some reason i'm still getting null on empolyee.userinfo ....

Comment: Then you did not do it correctly :). Your existing code generates `<input name="Name_f" ... />` but in order to bind to your model it needs to be `name= "UsersInfo.Name_f` which it will do if you followed my instructions.

Comment: But FGS, your editing data so always use a view model. And I just looked at your image and your excluding the `UsersInfo` from binding anyway so of course it will be `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke , any change you can show me an example how it should look like ?
i following your instructions and the name and the id property are formatted the like this UsersInfo.Name_f, UsersInfo.Name_l ?

Comment: Just start by removing the `[Bind]` attribute from your POST method to get it working (Sorry, I do not have time now to correct all the other awful code and bad practices you have)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , i thank you for your time , u been very helpful :)

Comment: @magdi you should be carefull with the bindings, maybe here its no problem to remove it, since you are using all the properties, but it can be a huge security gap in another action fi you do so. I suggest you to follow the link in the Microsoft-Generated Comment(go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=317598) to learn more about binding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your post method `[Bind(Include = "some property")]`. Which means you specified the list of properties only included in the model object, Other properties are not included in the model object.

Comment: There are far more errors in OP code than just the `[Bind]` attribute, and changing that would not do anything without all the other necessary changed