# Populate View Model Property with Partial Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a main view with a model `AViewModel`:

```
public class AViewModel
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }

    public BViewModel P2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have a partial view with `BViewModel`:

```
public class BViewModel
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }

    public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

From the main view I render the partial view as the following.

```
await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Views/_B.cshtml", Model.P2);
```

On the main view, on submit (`[HttpPost]` `Index` controller method), I'm expecting the `AViewModel.P2` to be populated with the `BViewModel` coming from the partial view, but it's not. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to populate the original property (namely `AViewModel.P2`) with information collected from the partial view?

In other words, the problem is that on the controller method, `model.P2.P1` and `model.P2.P2` are `null`

Comment: Because your partial view is based on `BViewModel` therefore create `name` attributes which are `name="P1"` etc, but to bind to `AViewModel` they need to be `name="P2.P1"` etc

Comment: Use an `EditorTemplate` (or ViewComponents), not a partial, but if you really want to use a partial, you need to to specify the `HtmlFieldPrefix`. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907) for example in mvc (may need to be modified for core-mvc)

Comment: You first comment is the correct answer sir, while the second comment seems not to be supported in MVC Core since `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.TemplateInfo` is read only.