# Partial viewmodel is null when posting to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've got a viewmodel that contains other viewmodels.

```
public class AggregateVM
{
    public BrandVM BrandVM { get; set; }
    public TinTypeVM TinTypeVM { get; set; }
}
```

When I http post to the controller action, the TinTypeVM is populated with my edited values, but the BrandVM viewmodel where I used a partial is always null.

Here's are the view.

```
@model SaveEF.ViewModels.AggregateVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditAggregate", "Aggregate")) 
{
    @Html.Partial("_EditBrand", Model.BrandVM)

    @Html.Label("Tin Name")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TinTypeVM.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Here's the partial view.

```
@model SaveEF.ViewModels.BrandVM
@Html.Label("Brand Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

Here's the controller action.

```
public ActionResult EditAggregate(AggregateVM vm)
{
    SaveBrand(vm.BrandVM);
    SaveTinType(vm.TinTypeVM);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How can I use partials in the view and still pass a single view model into the EditAggregate action? I've tried different parameters in Html.BeginForm("EditAggregate", "Aggregate", FormMethod.Post, new { vm = Model })) but that didn't help.

Comment: The `name` attributes of your partial are not prefixed correctly. One option is to pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the values from a nested complex object that is passed to a partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view)

Comment: Prefixing worked too. I tried it.

Comment: The correct approach is to use an `EditorTemplate` - rename you partial to `BrandVM.cshtml` and put it in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder - then in the view its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BrandVM)` (the solution you accepted might work but makes no sense - it now means you cannot use that partial in other models, so you are defeating the whole purpose of using a partial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You need to pass `AggregateVM` to your partial too.

**Long Answer**

The way you are doing it right now is:

```
@model SaveEF.ViewModels.BrandVM
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

So if you were to inspect the `name` generated for the editor would be `Name`. Thus when you post, the default model binder of MVC will look for a matching property in your view model. But you view model is like this:

```
public class AggregateVM
{
    public BrandVM BrandVM { get; set; }
    public TinTypeVM TinTypeVM { get; set; }
}
```

And there is no `Name` property.

**Fix**

You need to pass `AggregateVM` to your partial too.

```
@model SaveEF.ViewModels.AggregateVM
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BrandVM.Name)
```

and now the name for the editor will be `BrandVM.Name`. So when you post, the default model binder will look for the property `BrandVM.Name` and find it. Thus it will populate it.

The other alternative is to specify the `name` attribute yourself by using `@Html.Editor` or pass the attribute.