# Determine model type in Ajax Post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET MVC View. In my View I want to make an AJAX Post request to update a PartialView inside the view.

This is my Model:

```
public class HomeListViewModel
{
    public MainQueryViewModel MainQuery { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

And this is my View (which has a PartialView):

```
@model MyNameSpace.HomeListViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("List", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "browsePartialView", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="browsePartialView">
        @Html.Partial("_MainQuery", Model.MainQuery)
    </div>
}
```

Now this is my problem: I want AJAX to POST an object of type: `HomeListViewModel` to the controller, but AJAX Posts an object of type `MainQuery`.

This is my Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult List(HomeListViewModel HomeListViewModel)
{
    var myModel = HomeListViewModel;    // <-- an empty model is passed in

    // some action
}
```

If I change the param type to: `MainQuery`, then it works fine:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult List(MainQuery MainQuery)
{
    var myModel = MainQuery;    // <-- all ok

    // some action
}
```

Is there a way to tell AJAX what type of Model it should post to Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `Html.Partial()` is generating form controls with `name` attributes that relate to `MainQueryViewModel`, not `HomeListViewModel`.

The preferred method is to use an `EditorTemplate` which will prefix the `name` attributes so that you get `name="MainQuery.someProperty"` instead of `name="someProperty"` which you currently get.

Change the name of your partial to `MainQueryViewModel.cshtml` (to match the name of the class) and move it the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `/Views/yourControllerName/EditorTemplates`) folder, and to generate the html use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MainQuery)
```

Another option for adding the prefix is to pass the prefix using `additionalViewData`

```
@Html.Partial("_MainQuery", Model.MainQuery, 
new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "MainQuery" }})
```

And for a `HtmlHelper` extension method that simplifies it to `@Html.PartialFor(m => m.MainQuery, "_MainQuery")`, refer [getting the values from a nested complex object that is passed to a partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907).