# Change form context to ensure nested models are named correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In RoR, you can change the form context so that it properly builds the form element ids and names (e.g. `simple_fields_for myModel do |innerModel|`, or similar). I'm wondering what's the correct way to do this w/MVC5. For example...

**Models**

```
class Model1 {
    public Model2 M2 { get; set; }
}

class Model2 {
    public List<Model3> M3s { get; set; }
}

class Model3 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class MyController {
    public ActionResult Test(Model1 model) {
        View(model);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Model1

@using (MvcForm form = Html.BeginForm()) {
    Html.RenderPartial("_Model2", this.Model.M2);
}
```

If 3 `Model3` instances are posted back, the model state should be similar to:

```
M2.M3s[0].Name=Name1
M2.M3s[1].Name=Name2
M2.M3s[2].Name=Name3
```

In this case, the view is using a partial to render `Model2`, but the partial doesn't know that it's in the context of `this.Model.M2` and therefore does not prefix the ids and names generated with `Model2.` -- it simply starts them with `Model3`. The solution would be to use a new form context (not literally meaning `FormContext`), something like this:

```
@using (MvcForm form = Html.BeginForm()) {
    using (form.For(m => m.M2)) {
        Html.RenderPartial("_Model2", this.Model.M2);
    }
}
```

Note that `form.For` does not exist, but the intention is that it changes the current `ModelMetadata` to have the appropriate context and prefix of `M2`. Thus, anything rendered within that block would inherit that new context and the ids and names would be correctly generated.

Comment: Far easier is you use `EditorTemplate`'s rather than partials which will correctly add the prefixes (rename you partials to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Model2.cshtml` (to match the type) and then in the view use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.M2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually specify the prefix when you call `RenderPartial`, then the form values of your partial view fields will automatically receive that prefix:

```
Html.RenderPartial("_Model2", this.Model.M2, new ViewDataDictionary
{
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "M2" }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I did find this answer (of course after I typed all of this, even though I tried to find the answer before) which suggests a similar method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes I'll write up a helper to make this more straightforward and seamless!

Comment: @JoshM. No problems, yeah that's pretty handy to wrap it in a HTML helper method actually.

Comment: This works well, but is definitely cumbersome. Gets me moving forward for now, thanks! I'm surprised there's no built-in helper to handle this situation, seems it is pretty common as I run into it a lot. Another, more annoying, way to get around this is to have an editor template/partial for each "step" in the model chain. But that is such overkill.

Comment: @JoshM. Yeah it's still a bit of a shortcoming in the framework. Another alternative is to just pass the parent model into each of the partials, which isn't ideal either.