# Multiple radio button groups acting as one large grouping in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a problem when generating groups of radio buttons dynamically. The radio buttons represent the 3 mutually exclusive outcomes of a sporting fixture. Each grouping of 3 is then meant to represent a different fixture. However when I generate them they are all behaving as one giant group.

I'm using the following ***partial view*** to generate the radio buttons:

```
@model Competition.Models.MatchModel

@Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.Result, Result.Team1Win, new { id = Model.MatchID })
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.Result, Model.Team1.Name)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.Result, Result.Draw, new { id = Model.MatchID })
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.Result, "Draw")

@Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.Result, Result.Team2Win, new { id = Model.MatchID })
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.Result, Model.Team2.Name)
```

These partial views are then embedded within a ***parent view*** as follows:

```
<div>
@Html.Partial("Match", Model.Groups[0].groupMatch1)
</div>
<div>
@Html.Partial("Match", Model.Groups[0].groupMatch2)
</div>
```

The ***model*** for the partial views looks like this:

```
public class MatchModel
{
    public int MatchID { get; set; }

    public Country Team1 { get; set; }
    public Country Team2 { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

And finally ***Result is an enum*** representing the 3 possible outcomes:

```
public enum Result
{
    Team1Win,
    Draw,
    Team2Win
}
```

The problem I'm having is that this produces multiple sets of radio buttons however, they're all classified as one giant group, i.e. I can only select one option out o all of them. I want to be able to make one selection per group.

The ***html*** generated is as follows:

```
<div>

<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Result field       is required." id="1" name="Result" type="radio" value="Team1Win" />
<label for="Result">USA</label>

<input id="1" name="Result" type="radio" value="Draw" />
<label for="Result">Draw</label>

<input id="1" name="Result" type="radio" value="Team2Win" />
<label for="Result">Brazil</label>

</div>
<div>

<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Result field is required." id="2" name="Result" type="radio" value="Team1Win" />
<label for="Result">China</label>

<input id="2" name="Result" type="radio" value="Draw" />
<label for="Result">Draw</label>

<input id="2" name="Result" type="radio" value="Team2Win" />
<label for="Result">Germany</label>

</div>
```

I think the issue is that the Name attribute is identical for all of the radio buttons but I'm not sure how to have this be something different for each group.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes

Comment: thanks, that appears to have worked